# Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe

Tags: discussion

heute würde ich informiert, dass ich meine Aufnahmeprüfung beim Studienkolleg Darmstadt ( angegliedert mit Technische Universitaet Darmstadt) bestanden hab. Ich moechte ihnnen danken, fuer ihr Geduld, Hilfreichkeit und Aufmerksamkeit auf alle meine Fragen.

Ich glaube, dass ich fast zwei Jahren schon verbringt hab, um mein Traum, in Deutschland zu studieren, zu erfuellen. Und sicherlich kann ich sagen, dass ohne ihnnen, wuerde das nicht klappen. Und so, wieder, vielen Dank.

Ich werde noch hier sein, und wuerde versuchen, um zu hilfen, wo ich kann. Ich kann wahrscheinlich nicht so gut Deutsch wie die Andere hier, aber trotzdem wuerde ich versuchen, etwas zurueck zu geben.

Und nochmals, Vielen Dank.

Comment: Glückwunsch! (auch wenn das im Chat vermutlich besser aufgehoben wäre)